# Run a method once on every window activation handling arguments

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I'm currently working on an application where the user can login with multiple user accounts. Every time the app gets opened it shall reload the unread notification count for the current user account (there is one current account at a time, if he wants to use another he has to switch). I can detect the window getting into foreground with `Window.Current.Activated`.

As a second thing the user shall be able to change the user account on the fly. That includes using an URI scheme, e.g. myapp://changeuser?name=SecondAccount. If the user activates the app like this (remember it could be running already), it should use the SecondAccount from the start on. To handle the parameters I override the `Application.OnActivated` method.

Now if the user activates the already running app with parameters I have the problem that `Window.Current.Activated` gets called **before** `Application.OnActivated`. But if he passes parameters to switch accounts I don't want to check the old account anymore, only the new one.

So what's the best way to solve this problem? Overriding `OnResume` doesn't help as the app does not get suspended on Desktop when it's only losing focus.

Comment: Why not to subscribe to the *Window.Activated* event at the end of *Application.OnLaunched* or *Application.OnActivated*, eventually unsubscribe in suitable events - with this you can control when you need it to be called.

Comment: Why have you deleted the comments before that? However, there is no way to unsubscribe because what should be the condition? The situation is like you're in a olympic run and you're DNS if you do anything against the rules but they tell you the rules after you've started to run...

Comment: I've deleted the post as it doesn't answer your question (as I've read more). I thought about subscribing to *Window.Activated* in certain moment/event - *OnLaunched/OnActivated* there you can control when it's fired as I think.